# What is this gamma function that I see used in certain representations of the fokker-planck equation?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I often see the following stochastic function $\Gamma(x)$ defined based on only these requirements:

$$\langle\Gamma(x)\rangle=0$$
$$\langle\Gamma(x)\Gamma(x')\rangle=\delta(x-x')$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

My question is simply, what is $\Gamma$? Or, what is the class of functions that satisfy these conditions?

I suspect, based on the context I see this function in (Fokker-Planck / Langevin type equations), that $\Gamma(x) \sim \mathcal{N}(x)$, i.e., gamma has the same form as a normal distribution.

Comment: Can you please point out a ref where you see this function?

Comment: This paper https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.106.014140 gives the same two conditions. They reference "H. Risken, in The Fokker-Planck Equation (Springer, Berlin,1996), pp. 63–95.", though I have yet to find exactly what they are referencing in these 30+ pages

Comment: It's white noise. Basically it's the distributional derivative of Brownian motion. Typically that notation is used by physicists, but rarely by proper mathematicians.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $\langle f(x)f(x')\rangle$ is related to the auto-correlation of $f$. Therefore, the condition $\langle f(x)f(x')\rangle = \delta(x-x')$ is saying that the auto-correlation is zero everywhere except equality.

As @Tobsn pointed out in the comments, this is a condition of white noise. We can look to [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/283274/dirac-delta-function-and-correlation-functions) or [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#Continuous-time_white_noise) for more clarity. In particular, we find the relationship between $\Gamma$ and $\mathcal{N}$: their characteristic functions are similar in form.